# mysql-query other table condition PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have this table in mysql called safespot

```
+---------+---------------+
| term_id | userid | safe |
+---------+--------|------+
|       1 | 1      |  large number, unix timestamp here
|       1 | 2      | large number, unix timestamp here
|       1 | 3      | large number, unix timestamp here
|       1 | 4      | large number, unix timestamp here
+---------+--------+
```

And this is table `users`:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+
| id |    userid   |    cash     |
+----+-------------+-------------+
|  1 |     1       |    100000   |
|  2 |     2       |    100000   |
|  3 |     3       |    100000   |
+----+-------------+-------------+
```

how can i do something like

```
SELECT * FROM `users` where `userid`=1 and `cash`>= 1000 and " userid do not exist in table safespot" or "if the user exists in the safestop table, check if the current timestamp is higher than the safe colum)
```

So basically do a query that also would return it if userid dont exist in safespot table, or if it does, that timestamp is higher than safe_value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users u
LEFT JOIN safespot s ON s.userid = u.userid 
WHERE
    u.userid = 1
    AND u.cash = 1000
    AND (s.userid IS NULL OR s.safe > UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
```

This returns users where

- there is no entry in `safespot` for the given userid, or
- there is an entry in `safespot` with the value of `safe` greater than the current timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `userid`=1 AND `cash`>= 1000 AND (userid NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM safespot
    ) OR (userid IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM safespot WHERE safe < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
    )
)
```

Comment: but, it also have to have the condition, that it exist in the other table it has to check the safe value so its greather than current timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

Use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` like

```
SELECT u.* FROM `users` u
where u.`userid`=1 
and u.`cash` >= 1000 
and ( NOT EXISTS ( select 1 from safespot where userid <> u.userid)
or EXISTS (select 1 from safestop where userid = u.userid and safe < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP));
```

Comment: but, it also have to have the condition, that it exist in the other table it has to check the safe value so its greather than current timestamp?

Comment: @maria, see edit in answer if that helps. You just need to add another condition.